# How do you create a table cell factory in JavaFX to display a ChoiceBox?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am trying to display a ChoiceBox inside of a TableView in JavaFX. Right now I am just trying to test if I can get this working, so I am generating fake data within the cell factory, but I can't even get this to work.

My IDE is giving me the error that

```
forTableColumn (javafx.collections.ObservableList<T>) in ChoiceBoxTableCell cannot be applied
to             (javafx.collections.ObservableList<java.lang.String>)
```

Here is my code.

```
private ListView<RequirementsProperty> guiPropertyList;
private TableColumn<RequirementsProperty, String> guiSpecifierColumn;

guiSpecifierColumn.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn<RequirementsProperty, String>, TableCell<RequirementsProperty, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<RequirementsProperty, String> call(TableColumn<RequirementsProperty, String> param) {
                        ObservableList<String> testlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B", "C");
                        return ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(testlist);
                    }
                });
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I just want to display the list containing A, B, and C right now, and then I can move on to displaying my own data.

Comment: Did you try `ChoiceBoxTableCell.<RequirementsProperty, String>forTableColumn(testlist);`? What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(...)` returns a `Callback` itself (i.e. it returns the `cellFactory`, not the cell).

You can just do

```
ObservableList<String> testlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B", "C");
guiSpecifierColumn.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(testlist));
```

If you are implementing the factory yourself, its `call(...)` method needs to return the actual cell. In this case you would just construct a `ChoiceBoxTableCell` directly and return it:

```
guiSpecifierColumn.setCellFactory(
    new Callback<TableColumn<RequirementsProperty, String>, TableCell<RequirementsProperty, String>>() {
         @Override
         public TableCell<RequirementsProperty, String> call(TableColumn<RequirementsProperty, String> param) {
              ObservableList<String> testlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B", "C");
              return new ChoiceBoxTableCell(testlist);
         }
    });
```